# Count SemiPrimes task from Codility

Tags: python, primes

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from codility:

> A prime is a positive integer X that has exactly two distinct
> divisors: 1 and X. The first few prime integers are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 and
> 13.
>
> A semiprime is a natural number that is the product of two (not
> necessarily distinct) prime numbers. The first few semiprimes are 4,
> 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26.
>
> You are given two non-empty arrays P and Q, each consisting of M
> integers. These arrays represent queries about the number of
> semiprimes within specified ranges.
>
> Query K requires you to find the number of semiprimes within the range
> (P[K], Q[K]), where 1 ≤ P[K] ≤ Q[K] ≤ N.
>
> For example, consider an integer N = 26 and arrays P, Q such that:
>
> ```
> P[0] = 1    Q[0] = 26
> P[1] = 4    Q[1] = 10
> P[2] = 16   Q[2] = 20 The number of semiprimes within each of these ranges is as follows:
> ```
>
> (1, 26) is 10, (4, 10) is 4, (16, 20) is 0. Write a function:
>
> def solution(N, P, Q)
>
> that, given an integer N and two non-empty arrays P and Q consisting
> of M integers, returns an array consisting of M elements specifying
> the consecutive answers to all the queries.
>
> For example, given an integer N = 26 and arrays P, Q such that:
>
> ```
> P[0] = 1    Q[0] = 26
> P[1] = 4    Q[1] = 10
> P[2] = 16   Q[2] = 20 the function should return the values [10, 4, 0], as explained above.
> ```
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..50,000]; M is an integer within
> the range [1..30,000]; each element of arrays P and Q is an integer
> within the range [1..N]; P[i] ≤ Q[i].
> https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/11-sieve_of_eratosthenes/count_semiprimes/

My idea is to first find the primes in a given range, then find the semi primes by multiplying the primes with each other, calculate the prefix sum of the semiprimes and finally return the number of semiprimes in a given slice by subtracting the prefix sum of the lower index from the higher.

My code is:

```
def find_primes(n):
    primes = set(range(1, n+1))
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if i in primes:
            k = i * i
            while k <=n :
                if k in primes:
                primes.remove(k)
                k += i
        i += 1
    return list(primes)

def find_semi_primes(n):
    primes = find_primes(n)
    p = len(primes)
    semi_primes = set()
    for i in range(1, p):
        for j in range(i, p):
            p1 = primes[i]
            p2 = primes[j]
            if p1 * p2 > n:
                break
            semi_primes.add(p1 * p2)
    return semi_primes

def solution(N, P, Q):
    semi_primes = find_semi_primes(N)
    prefix_count = (N+1) * [0]
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        prefix_count[n] = prefix_count[n-1]
        if n in semi_primes:
            prefix_count[n] += 1

    q = len(P)
    result = q * [0]
    for i in range(q):
        result[i] = prefix_count[Q[i]] - prefix_count[P[i]-1]
    return result
```

It passes the correctness tests but fails the performance ones due to wrong answers, not due to theprocessing time. Can you see any mistake here? Thanks!

Comment: Please quote the problem statement in the body of the question, links are known to break.

Comment: `primes = find_primes(100)` - where did `100` come from?

Comment: @vnp I printed the first 100 primes to test and forgot to change it back. I edited the question

Comment: @vnp Actually this was the bug. The score is 100% now :D